# Why don't my photos appear on the map?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

The Assassin Creed Odyssey map displays photos taken by other players. The map display options also allow for these to be turned off, or to only display my own photos, or those taken by friends. None of the photos I have taken appear on the map when only displaying my photos (or at any other time). I understand that not all photos taken by all players are going to be displayed on the map at any one time, but thought that at least my photos would always be visible to me.

All the online instructions I have found through web searches only give instructions on how to enter the photo mode and take the photo, and do not mention the photos being displayed on the map.

I am sure I am online at the time, as my photos appear when I login to uPlay.

Is there a way to display all my photos on the map?

I am playing on PC and have never been able to see my photos, even after several days.

Comment: Have you ever been able to see your photos, or is this something like a recent problem?
And how much time has passed since you've taken photo(s) that don't appear on the map?

Comment: Never been able to see my photos, several days have passed since some photos were taken. Updated question to include new info.